# create percentage square in java instead circles

Tags: java, android, percentage

I am working in a existing project for an amazfit watchface. Code is based in java. The question is: In original project, for show battery, steps and sport percentage, show three circles. My idea is to draw a rectangle (or a line) instead the original circle. The problem is I am new programming in java and I don´t know for change this without FC app.

this watch has two screens: one active and other in stand-by mode (8colors only)

active mode draws circle, standby mode works with an png image.

This is the code (for circles):

```js
package es.xxxx.xxxx.widget;


    private final float startAngleBattery = 30;
    private final float arcSizeBattery = 360 - startAngleBattery - startAngleBattery;

  
    @Override
    public void init(Service service) {
        this.thickness = (int) service.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.xxxx_circles_thickness);

      
        this.textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        this.textPaint.setTypeface(ResourceManager.getTypeFace(service.getResources(), ResourceManager.Font.BEBAS_NEUE));
        this.textPaint.setTextSize(service.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.xxxx_circles_font_size));
        this.textPaint.setColor(service.getResources().getColor(R.color.xxxx_time_colour));
        this.textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        this.ring = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        this.ring.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        this.ring.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        this.ring.setStrokeWidth(this.thickness);

        this.circle = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        this.circle.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        this.circle.setStrokeWidth(1f);
        this.circle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, float width, float height, float centerX, float centerY) {
        int count = canvas.save();

        int radius = Math.round(Math.min(width / 2, height / 2)) - this.thickness;

        RectF oval = new RectF(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, centerX + radius, centerY + radius);

        // rotate from 0 to 270 degrees
        canvas.rotate(90, centerX, centerY);

        this.ring.setColor(this.backgroundColour);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, startAngleBattery, arcSizeBattery, false, ring);
        if (batterySweepAngle != null) {
            float px = getPointX(oval, centerX, startAngleBattery, batterySweepAngle);
            float py = getPointY(oval, centerY, startAngleBattery, batterySweepAngle);
            this.ring.setColor(this.batteryColour);
            canvas.drawArc(oval, startAngleBattery, batterySweepAngle, false, ring);
            canvas.drawCircle(px, py, this.thickness / 3f, circle);
            canvas.drawCircle(px, py, this.thickness / 6f, circle);
        }

      

        canvas.restoreToCount(count);

        
        if (this.batteryData != null) {
            String text = String.format("%02d", this.batteryData.getLevel() * 100 / this.batteryData.getScale());
            canvas.drawText(text, batteryTextLeft, batteryTextTop, textPaint);
        }

        

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataUpdate(DataType type, Object value) {
        switch (type) {
           
            case BATTERY:
                onBatteryData((Battery) value);
                break;
           }
    }

    @Override
    public List<DataType> getDataTypes() {
        return Arrays.asList(DataType.BATTERY);  

        private void onBatteryData(Battery battery) {
        this.batteryData = battery;
        if (batteryData == null) {
            this.batterySweepAngle = 0f;
        } else {
            float scale = batteryData.getLevel() / (float) batteryData.getScale();
            this.batterySweepAngle = Math.min(arcSizeBattery, arcSizeBattery * scale);
        }
    }

   private RectF nextOval(RectF oval) {
        oval.left = oval.left + this.thickness + MARGIN;
        oval.top = oval.top + this.thickness + MARGIN;
        oval.right = oval.right - this.thickness - MARGIN;
        oval.bottom = oval.bottom - this.thickness - MARGIN;
        return oval;
    }

    private float getPointX(RectF oval, float cx, float startAngle, float sweepAngle) {
        float width = oval.right - oval.left;
        return (float) (cx + (width / 2D) * Math.cos((sweepAngle + startAngle) * Math.PI / 180));
    }

    private float getPointY(RectF oval, float cy, float startAngle, float sweepAngle) {
        float height = oval.bottom - oval.top;
        return (float) (cy + (height / 2D) * Math.sin((sweepAngle + startAngle) * Math.PI / 180));
    }

    @Override
    public List<SlptViewComponent> buildSlptViewComponent(Service service) {
        Typeface timeTypeFace = ResourceManager.getTypeFace(service.getResources(), ResourceManager.Font.BEBAS_NEUE);

        SlptLinearLayout power = new SlptLinearLayout();
        power.alignX = 2;
        power.alignY = 2;
        power.add(new SlptPowerNumView());
        power.setTextAttrForAll(
                service.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.xxxx_circles_font_size_slpt),
                -1,
                timeTypeFace
        );
        power.setStart(
                (int) service.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.xxxx_battery_text_left_slpt),
                (int) service.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.xxxx_battery_text_top_slpt));
        SlptPowerArcAnglePicView powerArcView = new SlptPowerArcAnglePicView();
        powerArcView.setImagePicture(Util.assetToBytes(service, "battery_splt.png"));
        powerArcView.start_angle = (int) startAngleBattery + 180 - 3;
        powerArcView.full_angle = (int) arcSizeBattery + 6;

       

        return Arrays.asList(power, powerArcView);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's way too much code to go through, you need to break it down in a simpler format

Comment: Thank you @chinloyal, I simplify code only for my problem.

Comment: edit your ondraw method to draw rect instead of arc or oval or circle.

Comment: the problem is it, I don´t find any example for Draw.Rect, and use png image. Second problem is this percentage only uses a half of screen.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still searching...

You can draw the rectangular in the "draw" function that runs in loop constantly when screen is on, however, screen off (SLPT mode) uses ingenic's libraries to draw (function buildSlptViewComponent) and there is the real problem.

I don't want to get into details because it would be pages, so have a look at [GreatFit project](https://github.com/GreatApo/GreatFit).